# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.BackHandler.addEventListener')

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using **react-native: 0.40 with react: 15.4.2 and react-native-router-flux: 3.37.0** and I've been getting this error. Although everything I get this error on iOS, the app runs with no issue. But on Android, whenever I press the back button, the app crashes.

My assumption is that react native back button is conflicting with react-native-router-flux package.

Any help would be appreciated.

[evaluating '_reactNative.BackHandler.addEventListener'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeyYZ.png)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are importing BankHandler from react-native and not react, it should be

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';
```

NOT

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react';
```

That was what caused the error for me :)

Comment: I did the same mistake, imported it from the wrong library.

Comment: This doesn't work .

Answer (score 4):

Try react-native@0.44.0 and react@16.0.0-alpha.6. I believe that this was fixed here: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/pull/1819

I had the same error and after installing the above versions it works for me.

Comment: Solved it for me!